# Leg pressing the deadlift but not the squat, why?

Tags: squats, deadlifts

A good advice I heard for getting more leg activation in deadlift is to leg press the earth away when doing the pull and not starting with shoulder. However, this same cue is not given in squat altho many similar muscle groups are used. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a deadlift, you are in a bent over position. This makes it easier to start the lift with your back and upper body, instead of starting the drive with your legs. The "press the earth away" shifts the emphasis to starting that upward drive with the legs.

The squat, because the body is in a more upright position, it's harder to start with the upper body, so a cue isn't really needed for that. You can still push the butt backwards and then lift with the upper body which is bad form, but the initial motion is still with the legs.